# Add a dependency to a non GWT project from a GWT project

Tags: java, gwt, maven

I am working with Maven GWT. The project is working properly when I run it stand alone. But when I try to add a dependency to a non GWT project(A simple java project), I get the following error when I do a Maven package.

GWT Module My.Package.MyModule not found in project sources or resources.

Of course, I added the MyModule.gwt.xml in the non GWT project and inherited that module from my GWT project in the pom file.

I tried to google for the answer but ended up with nothing..

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `pom.xml` files would be appreciated. It seems that you're trying to execute GWT plugin on a project that does not have any GWT sources (a simple java project).

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a common problem when you are using Maven reactor structure. After adding the gwt.xml file in the non-gwt project and inheriting in the gwt project, you also have to edit the pom files of the non-gwt project and the parent maven project.

There are detailed instructions that will help you solve the problem at Mojo Codehaus:
http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/multiproject.html